# How to use images to change dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

what I'm trying to accomplish is to have image thumbnails replace the dropdown box in a woocommerce variation product page.  The way I went to trying to get that to work is when a user clicks on an variation product image, the (will be hidden) dropdown box will change to the correct value just as if the user had interacted with the dropdown box itself. the file I'm working with is variable.php.

Here is a snippet of the code. All my custom codes start with the option tag loop just before the closing Select tag.

```
$loop = 0; foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++; $countimg = 0;?>
    <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>" >
            <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>                         
            <?php
            if ( is_array( $options ) ) {

                if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                    $selected_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                    $selected_value = $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                } else {
                    $selected_value = '';
                }

                                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {

                    $orderby = wc_attribute_orderby( $name );

                    switch ( $orderby ) {
                        case 'name' :
                        $args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => false, 'menu_order' => false );
                        break;
                        case 'id' :
                        $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'menu_order' => false, 'hide_empty' => false );
                        break;
                        case 'menu_order' :
                        $args = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false );
                        break;
                    }

                    $terms = get_terms( $name, $args );
                    $count = 1;

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) )
                            continue;                               
                        echo '<option id="' . $count . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';                          
                        $count++;}
                    } else {                            
                        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                            echo '<option id="' . $count . '" value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';                            
                            $count++;}

                        }
                    }
                    ?>
        </select> 

                <div>
                    <?php foreach ( $available_variations as $available_variation ) {
                        $countimg++;
                        $image_links = $available_variation['image_link'];
                    echo '<img id="' . $countimg . '" src="' . $image_links . '" onclick="selectVariationOption(this.id)" style="height:65px; margin-bottom:5px;">';
                    }?>
                </div>

                <script>
                function selectVariationOption(clicked_id) {                
                document.getElementById("<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>").selectedIndex = clicked_id;
                }
                </script>

                <?php
                if ( sizeof($attributes) == $loop )
                    echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
                ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I did here was I added a numerical ID to the option tags and increases with each additional option available.  I then showed the available image variations and added a numerical ID that looped to match the corresponding option ID. Finally, I used a simple javascript that when an image is clicked, the dropdown box changes to the correct selectedIndex.  The problem is, the page doesn't react to the changes as if the dropdown box was directly interacted with.  In short, nothing happens but the dropdown box changing visual value.  I want it so that clicking on the image would be the exact same as clicking on an option in the dropdown box.

Let me know if you need more clarification or information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered [Variation Swatches](http://www.woothemes.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/)?

Comment: Luckly I do have the Variation Swatches and Photos 1.3.0 plugin installed.  Activated it and added the photos but now the price isn't showing.  I originally wanted to avoid using this plugin because it would require me to manually update each product listing.

Comment: Probably depends on your theme's template. I would assume it works correctly "out of the box". I'm not sure why you have to edit each product, but still it is probably less time than you'd spend trying to re-write Variation Swatches from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Variation Swatches and Photos plugin worked. Just had to go in and edit the plugin's variable.php to show all the information that was missing from my original variable.php file. Now I just have to spend a couple hours editing each product.